# Можно ли запустить службу OpenVPN с отключенной службой Windows «DHCP-Клиент»?

Tags: openvpn

Здравствуйте. Не удается запустить службу OpenVPN на Windows XP, где отключена служба клиента DHCP. Такая политика.
Возможно ли как то запустить OpenVPN без службы клиента DHCP?
Ошибка: Служба OpenVPN Service является зависимой от службы "DHCP-клиент"...